# Convert PDF of single page to image

Tags: python, pdf, pdf2image

I am trying to convert pdf to an image using the following code

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pages = convert_from_path('Sample.pdf', 50, poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-20.11.0\bin')
pages[0].save('OutImage.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

The code is working but I am trying to control the output image to make its size 1389 x 1965
Can you guide me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [size parameter](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image/blob/master/pdf2image/pdf2image.py#L81) of `convert_from_path` function

> size -> Size of the resulting image(s), uses the Pillow (width, height) standard

Example of using it:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pages = convert_from_path("eng.pdf", 50, size=(1389, 1965))
pages[0].save("OutImage.jpg", "JPEG")
```

```
$ file OutImage.jpg
OutImage.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1389x1965, components 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What is the dimension for A4 page size?

Comment: it is 3508 x 2480

Comment: I am not sure but I don't think this is a proper dimension. Here's a link to a sample pdf file https://www.mediafire.com/file/cng794a6c8oyll9/MySample.pdf/file

Comment: change 50 to 300 as it's A4 size for 300 dpi